# Nontrivial homogeneous Vector bundle

Tags: lie-groups, differential-topology, vector-bundles, homogeneous-spaces, linear-groups

What is an example of a Lie group $ G $ and a subgroup $ G' $, both with finitely many connected components, such that $ G\mathbin{/}G' $ is a nontrivial vector bundle? This is a follow up to

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345905/homogeneous-manifold-deformation-retracts-onto-compact-submanifold

EDIT:

Take $ G $ to be the connected group
$$
G=SE_2:= \left \{ \
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & x \\
-b & a & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : a^2+b^2=1 \right \} 
$$
there is a connected group $ V $ of translations up each vertical line
$$
V= \left \{ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : y \in \mathbb{R} \right \} 
$$
Now if we include the rotation by 180 degrees
$$
\tau:=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $G' = \langle V, \tau \rangle$ has two connected components and
$$
G\mathbin{/}G'
$$
is the Moebius band (hopefully? It could still be the cylinder but I don't know how to check)

Comment: Hint: The (open) Möbius strip is diffeomorphic to the space of affine lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can you think of a way to make this into a homogeneous space?

Comment: I edited my question. Is that what you were thinking of? There should a transitive action by $ E_2 $ that translates lines around and then the $ O_2 $ part rotates them. I think the subgroup I modded out by is the stabilizer of a vertical line, except the rotation $ \tau $ doesn't seem right. Maybe a reflection instead?

Comment: If you choose $SE(2)$, then the stabilizer is indeed $\langle V,\tau\rangle$ (note that $SE(2)$ doesn't include reflections). To show this, note that every element of $SE(2)$ consists of a translation followed by a rotation. To preserve the $x$-axis, the rotational part must be $\pm 1$ and the the translation must have vanishing $y$-component.

Comment: As for showing this space $M$ is the Möbius strip, you can equip it with the standard fiber bundle structure by the mapping each line to the unique parallel line which passes through the origin, giving a map $M\to\mathbb{RP^1}\cong S^1$ where the fiber above a line $l\in\mathbb{RP}^1$ corresponds to $l^\perp$. From there you can show that this line bundle is nontrivial e.g. using two local trivializtions.

Comment: @Kajelad is there a transitive action on the Moebius strip by a 2 dimensional lie group (it would have to be the non abelian one, the solvable non nilpotent unimodular group $ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & \frac{1}{a} \end{bmatrix} $ ) ? Or is a 3d group like SE2 the best we can do? Also would you mind posting your comments as an answer? If not I'll just post an answer to my own question because I found the example of $ SO_3(\mathbb{C})/SO_2(\mathbb{C}) $ being the tangent bundle of sphere $ S^2 $.

Comment: I'm not sure what "the best" means here, but $2$ dimensions is impossible. It an $n$-dimensional lie group $G$ acts transitively on an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, then the action must be locally free (in the sense that the fundamental vector fields are nonvanishing). This implies, for instance, that $TM$ must be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example is the Möbius strip, which admits a homogeneous $E(2)$ (or $SE(2)$) structure. To see this note that the set of affine lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (A manifold I'll call $M$) is diffeomorphic to the Möbuis strip.

One way to see this is using the projection $M\to\mathbb{RP}^1\cong S^1$ given by mapping each line to the unique parallel line which passes through the origin. Each fiber $\pi^{-1}(l)$ of this projection can be identified with the orthogonal compliment of $l$., and the resulting bundle has typical fiber $\mathbb{R}$ and is nontrivial. (If you're familiar, this construction is equivalent to the [tautological line bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_bundle) of $\mathbb{RP}^1$.)

This set of lines admits a transitive $E(2)$ action, so we have $M\cong E(2)/G$, where $G$ is the stabilizer of the $x$-axis.

Comment: I am familiar with the tautological line bundle! And this example is so super cool! Also love the fact in your comment that a Lie group mod discrete subgroup is always a parallelizable manifold! Is that basically because Lie groups are always parallizable and the map is a covering map? I guess you need something extra because hyperbolic plane is parallelizable but covers genus g>2 surfaces which are not parallelizable?

Comment: Also side note does your fact from the comment together with Malcev's theorem (that every compact nilmanifold is quotient of simply connected nilpotent lie group by a cocompact lattice)  imply every compact nilmanifold is orientable (indeed parallelizable)? I'm very surprised by that because there are lots of nonorientable compact solvmanifolds, for example the Klein bottle!

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira To the first comment, Lie groups are parallelizable, but you need more than a covering map to preserve this property. The key point is that Lie groups are parallelized by left-invariant vector fields, and the covering map acts by left translations, so these fields descend to the quotient. An alternate argument is that if a fundamental vector field vanishes at $p$, then its one-parameter subgroup is contained in the point stabilizer $G_p$, and so the dimensions can't add up.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira To the second comment, I'm unfamiliar with Mal'cev's theorem, but it indeed seems to imply that compact nilmanifolds are parallelizable.

Answer (score 0):

$ SO_3(\mathbb{C})/SO_2(\mathbb{C}) $ is the tangent bundle of the sphere $ S^2 $. This vector bundle is nontrivial ($ S^2 $ is not parallelizable).